# Trying to install deeplearning4j

Tags: java, git, maven

I have "git-cloned" **nd4j and Canova** and have compiled them. 
Now trying to do same for **deeplearning4j**, after "git-cloning" deeplearning4j, I cd into the directory as instructed and then run:

`mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`

I get the error :

> "Failed to execute goal on project deeplearning4j-core: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:jar:0.4-rc1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find org.nd4j:nd4j-x86:jar:0.4-rc1-SNAPSHOT in
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of sonatype-nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are
>   forced".

Please any ideas what I might be doing wrong. 
I am using **Windows 7 64bit**

Comment: It sounds you didn't check the SNAPSHOT repository, cause this snapshot version is not in the given repository.

Answer (score 1):

DL4J co-creator here. What are you trying to do? If you would just like to use the library, the easiest way to do it is by downloading the libs through Maven using IntelliJ. If you planning on helping us build the lib, then you should download the source files... help@skymind.io